# How to get array in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

`$offers` variable include three value of ids.
Now,I would like to fetch these ids from database and store them in `$data['offer_day']` :

```
 $offers = explode('+',$post['offer_day']) ;
```

---

when I use this foreach, it stores just one and last query. now, how can I have three queries on `$data['offer_day']` and how can use them in `view` ?

```
    foreach($offers as $o){
        $offer_day = $this->m_general->get('coupons' , array('id'=>$o) , false );
        $data['offer_day']    = $offer_day->result_array();
        if(!$data['offer_day']) exit("error");
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide your `$this->m_general->get()` function, and a `var_dump()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update like this:

```
$data['offer_day'] = array();
foreach($offers as $o){
      $offer_day = $this->m_general->get('coupons' , array('id'=>$o) , false );
        $data['offer_day'][]    = $offer_day->result_array();
        if(!$data['offer_day']) exit("error");
    }

$this->load->view('your view file', $data);
```

And in the view file you can access like **`$offer_day`** which will be an array.

Comment: ok, it works fine, now how can access id of the first item of `$offer_day`?

Comment: You can access like a normal indexed array. ie $offer_day[0]

Answer (score 1):

Put them into an array.

```
$data['offer_day'] = array();
foreach($offers as $o){
    $offer_day = $this->m_general->get('coupons' , array('id'=>$o) , false );
    $data['offer_day'][]    = $offer_day->result_array();
    if(!$data['offer_day']) exit("error");
}

var_dump($data['offer_day']);
```

Comment: ok, it works fine, now how can access `id ` of the first item of $offer_day?

Comment: I'm using `$offer_day[0]['id']`, but it not return any thing !